One proof about variable substitution of generalized functions

Let $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ be two open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and assume that the map $\Phi: \Omega_1 \to \Omega_2$ is a diffeomorphism. We establish a relationship that maps a distribution on $\Omega_2$ to a distribution on $\Omega_1$. For $u \in D'(\Omega_2)$ and $\phi \in D(\Omega_1)$, we define $\Phi^*u$ as follows:
$$
\langle \Phi^*u, \phi(x)\rangle := \langle u, \phi(\Phi^{-1}(y)) \det J(\Phi(y)) \rangle = \left\langle u, \frac{\phi(\Phi^{-1}(y))}{\det J_\Phi(\Phi^{-1}(y))} \right\rangle.
$$
Here, $\Phi$ is a smooth function with compact support on $\Omega_1$, and the composite function $\Phi^{-1}$ is a smooth function with compact support on $\Omega_2$. Since $\Phi$ is a diffeomorphism, the determinant $|\det J(\Phi^{-1}(y))|$ is a smooth, nonzero function. This ensures that the above expression is well-defined.
To prove that $\Phi^*u$ defines a distribution on $\Omega_1$, we use the following argument: for any compact set $K \subset \Omega_1$, there exists a non-negative constant $C$ and a sufficiently small function $\phi \in C^\infty(\Omega_1)$ such that
$$
|\langle \Phi^*u, \phi \rangle| \leq C \sup_{|\alpha| \leq p} \left\| \frac{\partial^\alpha (\phi(\Phi^{-1}(y)))}{\det J_\Phi(\Phi^{-1}(y))} \right\|_{L^\infty(K)}.
$$
We need to apply the chain rule repeatedly. $\color{red}{\text{The key observation is that the derivatives above}}$$\color{red}{\text{ yield a linear combination of derivatives of $\phi$ up to order $p$, }}$$\color{red}{\text{where the coefficients are polynomials in derivatives of $\Phi(y)$ up to order $p+1$.}}$ Since we are restricted to a compact set $K$, these compact sets are uniformly bounded (this bound may depend on $K$), and by adjusting the constant $C$ in the inequality above, we ultimately obtain
$$
|\langle \Phi^*u, \phi \rangle| \leq C' \sup_{|\alpha| \leq p} \| \partial^\alpha \phi \|_{L^\infty(K)}.
$$

The text above (from a lecture note) introduce variable substitution of generalized functions. It tried to show that $\Phi^* u$ defines a distribution by checking its definition. But I didn't realize the $\color{red}{\text{red text}}$ above. I think that the coefficients of this derivative should be something like fractions instead of polynomials. Because the denominator of it, det of Jacobi, should also be differentiated. And probably it cannot be reduced. So I think the coefficients should be some fractions.
Is there anything wrong? Or I misunderstood some concept?

We can write
$
\langle \Phi^* u, \varphi \rangle
= \langle u, g\hat\varphi \rangle,
$
where $g=\det(J\circ\Phi)\in C^\infty$ and $\hat\varphi=\varphi\circ\Phi^{-1},$ and $g\hat\varphi$ is just pointwise multiplication of $g$ with $\hat\varphi.$
If you can show that $\langle \hat u, \varphi\rangle := \langle u, \hat\varphi \rangle$ defines a distribution $\hat u$, then you can just apply that a $C^\infty$ function (here $g$) times a distribution (here $\hat u$) is also a distribution.
